# How do I convert varchar value is into a byte array using vb.net

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, vb.net

I have the following `varchar(MAX)` value

and I want to save it in a byte array using vb.net :

Please note that the dots are separators and I want each number to be in an array field such

`array[0]=255 , array[1]=216 .... and so on`

```
255.216.255.224.0.16.74.70.73.70.0.[snip].69.20.81.45.192.255.217.
```

Comment: Have a look at http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets7p7.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use 'Split' Function like this :

```
Dim Split1 As String() = yourString.Split(".")
```

Comment: can you write me a code sample on how i use it to split that huge string back into the array file... I really appreciate your help

Comment: Dim LineOfText As String
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim aryTextFile() As String

        LineOfText = CType(dt.Rows(0)("Data"), String)

        aryTextFile = LineOfText.Split(".")

        For i = 0 To UBound(aryTextFile)

            MsgBox(aryTextFile(i))

        Next i